# Not allow a blank character / space in a input form

Tags: javascript, forms, character

Is it possible to not allow a blank character / space in a input form like below?

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="30" name="email" class="formfield w0">
```

Comment: How do you mean "not allow"? Validation, or entry of the character?

Comment: I think there is already a lot of information about this issue.

Comment: Cannot add a new answer, and IMO the linked one is only partially related, it's possible to use the following `pattern="\S+"`, this will prevent the browser to submit the form when the field contain a single character that is a white space. Ideally add also something like `title="Insert your email without spaces"` for improved usability, see more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLpY/). Relevant code:

```js
 $(function() {
        $('#input1').on('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 32){
                console.log('Space Detected');
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input1" />
```

Comment: really weird, it just doesn't seem to work on my page... I can still add spaces in the email input!
goo.gl/0TXWGV

Comment: Your jQuery version is old (1.5.2). You can update jQuery or use `live()` instead of `on()`.

Comment: Yes, I just found the problem, indeed it was the old version. Thanks for your time for looking at it.

Comment: I have used .live which worked. Updating js gave problems

Comment: That is not enough when content come from a copy-paste, or when the textbox is auto-filled by the browser.  Event should be on 'change' with: `$('#input1').val($('#input1').val().replace(/ /g, ''));`

Comment: it's not working if i am copying and paste any text with including space, ie: "{first}           {last}"

Comment: @Raidri Please Update It, as soon as possible. :)

Comment: if user copy and paste the input, it does not work.

Comment: A more modern and shorter approach is `$('#search-input').keydown(e => e.which != 32).keyup(e => $(e.target).val((i, v) => v.replace(/ /g, '')));`

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5's extended input types to apply constraint validation, which will prevent submitting the form with invalid emails in modern browsers:

```
<input type="email" value="" maxlength="30" name="email" class="formfield w0">
```

In older browsers, you can detect that the input's type is not "email", as it will default to "text" when a value is considered invalid.  I'd recommend blocking the submission of the form, rather than preventing default action of the space key, which could be inadvertently circumvented by pasting or via other input methods.

The following code is an example of this, and should be executed after the document is ready:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('myform');

if (frm.email.type === 'text') {
    frm.onsubmit = function () {
        if (/\s/.test(frm.email.value)) {
            // Tell your user the field is invalid here, e.g.
            frm.email.className = 'invalid';

            // Prevent form submission
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hgc7C/**

Don't forget that this is not a substitute for server-side form validation.

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice solution, only in this case I don't need it to lighten up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using javascript/JQuery.

If you want it for all text boxes, then do as below.

```
$(function() {
    $('.formfield input[type=text]').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32)
            return false;
    });
});
```

If you want it for a specific textbox, then add an id to the textbox input and replace `.formfield input[type=text]` with `#textBoxId`