# How to validate custom user model username to prevent blank spaces

Tags: python, django

Here's my code:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
```

How do I prevent users from using blank spaces in the `username` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UnicodeUsernameValidator` validator that [Django itself uses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator

username = models.CharField(
    _('username'), max_length=30, unique=True, 
    validators=[UnicodeUsernameValidator()]
)
```

You could, depending on your use case, also subclass [`AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) to avoid having to redefine some fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this on your front end.
You can get a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLpY/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#input1').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32)
            return false;
    });
});
```

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19024976/11888426)